# July 29, 2016 – 17th Annual System Administrator Appreciation Day

Tags: discussion

*Yes. This is not a question. I know. This will be closed, and I'm fine with this. But I think all the sysadmin people out there deserve this, so this is just a [short reminder](http://sysadminday.com/) ... and I hope this doesn't get too much downvoted.*

--

> Your network is secure, your computer is up and running, and your printer is jam-free. Why? Because you’ve got an awesome sysadmin (or maybe a whole IT department) keeping your business up and running. So say IT loud; say IT proud …
>
> **Happy SysAdmin Day!**
>
> Wait… what exactly is SysAdmin Day? Oh, it’s only the single greatest 24 hours on the planet… and pretty much the most important holiday of the year. It’s also the perfect opportunity to pay tribute to the heroic men and women who, come rain or shine, prevent disasters, keep IT secure and put out tech fires left and right.
>
> At this point, you may be thinking, “Great. I get it. My sysadmin is a rock star. But now what?” Glad you asked! Proper observation of SysAdmin Day includes (but is not limited to):
>
> - Cake & Ice cream
> - Pizza
> - Cards
> - Gifts
> - Words of gratitude
> - Custom t-shirts celebrating the epic greatness of your SysAdmin(s)
> - Balloons
> - Streamers
> - Confetti
>
> **Show your appreciation**
>
> Friday, July 29, 2016, is the 17th annual System Administrator Appreciation Day. On this special international day, give your System Administrator something that shows that you truly appreciate their hard work and dedication. (All day Friday, 24 hours, your own local time-zone).
>
> Let’s face it, System Administrators get no respect 364 days a year. This is the day that all fellow System Administrators across the globe, will be showered with expensive sports cars and large piles of cash in appreciation of their diligent work. But seriously, we are asking for a nice token gift and some public acknowledgement. It’s the least you could do.
>
> Consider all the daunting tasks and long hours (weekends too.) Let’s be honest, sometimes we don’t know our System Administrators as well as they know us. Remember this is one day to recognize your System Administrator for their workplace contributions and to promote professional excellence. Thank them for all the things they do for you and your business.

**Happy SysAdmin Day to all of you!**

Comment: Thank you, @gf_.  <3